# El Android App Bundle no se ha firmado

Tags: android, android-studio, firma-digital, google-play-console, google-play-services

Empecé creando una app de Android en un Mac. Y luego la pasé a un Windows para terminarla y subirla a la tienda de Google. Desde el Mac no lo firmé, solo lo compilé en dispositivos virtuales y físicos. Fue en Windows donde si lo firmé (usando Android Studio y no la consola).
Todo parecía funcionar bien hasta que intenté subir mi primera versión de prueba en formato ".aab" a la consola de la play store.
Cuando se subió el fichero me salió esto:

[image: Android App Bundle no firmado]

Aún así me dejaba pulsar en revisar la versión. Pero al hacerlo, me salió el siguiente aviso y se quedó ahí cargando en bucle:

[image: Aviso]

He intentado a recargar la página con control+f5, usar otro navegador, hacer un clean y usar otras claves de firmado. Incluso he vuelto a crear el proyecto desde cero y he copiado y pegado el código del proyecto anterior al nuevo, y generando nuevas claves... Pero sigue ocurriendo lo mismo...

Desde Android Studio he creado las claves (ficheros pepk y jks), y luego con ellas creo que es dónde se hace la firma. Es decir, estos dos pasos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y luego en la consola de la play store, está marcarda está opción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Quizás deba elegir una opción distinta a la que recomienda Google?

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Gracias de antemano :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Si vas a realizar un update debes usar el mismo Kesytore o firma usada al subir tu primera versión de la aplicación.

Si tu aplicación es nueva y deseas subir un Android App Bundle y seleccionas la opción:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

es importante que te suscribas al programa generando la llave, indica una ruta donde se generará :

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

cuando la obtengas ve a [**Firmas de apps de Play**](https://play.google.com/console/developers/app/keymanagement) (o ve a `Configuración` > `Integridad de la app` de Play Console )y selecciona la primera opción donde subirás el archivo generado en el paso anterior

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Posteriormente puedes generar tu .AAB como lo realizas, recuerda que tanto la primera versión como las posteriores deben ser firmadas con el mismo certificado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Tanto el .APK como el .AAB deben ser generados como release:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

revisa [Usa la firma de apps de Play](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756)

Comment: Gracias por responder. Lo que me has dicho no me ha servido del todo, pero después de probar un montón de cosas complejas, he encontrado la solución...
Resulta que estaba creando la build como "debug" y no como "release"...
Mamma mía! jajaja!

Comment: @Jokerlocco la versión debug es la que se firma con el keystore de desarrollo por ejemplo cuando  subes de Android Studio tu aplicación, se sube el .apk de debug, para subir a Google Play debes generar siempre en el directorio release. Agregué esa info en la respuesta.

Answer (score 0):

Lei :https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/building-your-first-app-bundle-bbcd228bf631

Así decidí firmarla yo mismo:

Para generar el aab ( que no me lo firma  >:(  ).

```
./**<path to>**/gradlew bundleDebug --project-dir=**<path to>** --stacktrace
```

Y para firmar el aab:

```
jarsigner -keystore ./**<path to>**/app/keystore.jks ./**<path to>**/app/build/outputs/bundle/release/app-release.aab key0
```

Te pide la password y listo.

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).